# Nginx reverse proxy load upstream list from external file

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm writing an automation to add new servers to the upstream.
Currently my upstream block is embedded in the reverse proxy configuration file with a `proxy_pass  http://backbones;` directive in the `server` block.

I would like to separate the upstream block to a different file so it will be easier to parse it.

Is it possible to load the upstream block from a different file?

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Create a file named `/etc/nginx/upstream.conf`
Put you initial upstreams here:

```
server ip:port;
server ip:port;
```

Change your config (ie `default.conf`) to something like this:

```
upstream cluster {
    include /etc/nginx/upstream.conf;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cluster;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Then you can parse and edit `upstream.conf` and do `nginx -s reload` to make the configuration live.

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks!
One important thing to keep in mind is that putting the `upstream.conf` in the conf.d folder will not work and you need to put as mentioned in the nginx root folder.

Comment: It fails on 1.19.0 as `nginx: [emerg] directive "server" has no opening "{"  in /etc/nginx/upstream.conf:1`

Answer (score 0):

And for proxy_pass directive?
It's possible to configure an external file ?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html 
it seems that you can use it also